Confused about how to use Microsoft.AspNetCore.SystemWebAdapters while trying to port from old ASP.NET website to new ASP.NET Core web app
I created a new ASP.NET Core 8 MVC web app, and added Microsoft.AspNetCore.SystemWebAdapters dependency to it.
Program.cs:
using OldHandlers;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
builder.Services.AddSystemWebAdapters(); // Register SystemWebAdapters

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();

// Register SystemWebAdapters middleware
app.UseSystemWebAdapters();

// Define endpoints
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapGet("/myhandler", async context =>
    {
        var adapter = new AspNetCoreHttpContextAdapter(context);
        var handler = new MyHandler();
        handler.ProcessRequest(adapter);
    });
});

app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapRazorPages();

app.Run();

And I have:
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SystemWebAdapters;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using OldHandlers;

public class AspNetCoreHttpContextAdapter : IHttpContextAdapter
{
    private readonly HttpContext _context;

    public AspNetCoreHttpContextAdapter(HttpContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public string ResponseContentType
    {
        get => _context.Response.ContentType;
        set => _context.Response.ContentType = value;
    }

    public void WriteResponse(string content)
    {
        _context.Response.WriteAsync(content);
    }

    public async Task<string> ReadRequestBodyAsync()
    {
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(_context.Request.Body))
        {
            return await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
        }
    }

    public void SetStatusCode(int statusCode)
    {
        _context.Response.StatusCode = statusCode;
    }

    public object GetRouteData(string key)
    {
        return _context.Items[key];
    }
}

In my old website, I created a new handler:
public class MyHttpHandler : IHttpHandler, IRequiresSessionState
{
     public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
     {
         var adapter = new SystemWebHttpContextAdapter(new HttpContextWrapper(context));
         var handler = new MyHandler();
         handler.ProcessRequest(adapter);
     }

     public bool IsReusable => false;
}

and:
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web;
using OldHandlers;

public class SystemWebHttpContextAdapter : IHttpContextAdapter
{
    private readonly HttpContextBase _context;

    public SystemWebHttpContextAdapter(HttpContextBase context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public string ResponseContentType
    {
        get => _context.Response.ContentType;
        set => _context.Response.ContentType = value;
    }

    public void WriteResponse(string content)
    {
        _context.Response.Write(content);
    }

    public async Task<string> ReadRequestBodyAsync()
    {
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(_context.Request.InputStream))
        {
            return await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
        }
    }

    public void SetStatusCode(int statusCode)
    {
        _context.Response.StatusCode = statusCode;
    }

    public object GetRouteData(string key)
    {
        return _context.Items[key];
    }
}

I also created a .NET Standard 2.0 library to contain the concrete handler implementation:
namespace OldHandlers
{
    public class MyHandler
    {
        public void ProcessRequest(IHttpContextAdapter context)
        {
            context.ResponseContentType = "text/plain";
            context.WriteResponse("Hello, World!");
        }
    }
}

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace OldHandlers
{
    public interface IHttpContextAdapter
    {
        string ResponseContentType { get; set; }
        void WriteResponse(string content);
        Task<string> ReadRequestBodyAsync();
        void SetStatusCode(int statusCode);
        object GetRouteData(string key);
    }
}

What I don't understand is that if I use Microsoft.AspNetCore.SystemWebAdapters, then do I need to create my adapter classes, AspNetCoreHttpContextAdapter and SystemWebHttpContextAdapter?
I would appreciate it if someone tried out a POC. I need a shared .netStandard library between the old asp.net website and the new .NET 8 ASP.NET Core WebApp. And HttpContext should be supported by the shared library.

With Microsoft.AspNetCore.SystemWebAdapters, you might not need to create custom adapter classes (AspNetCoreHttpContextAdapter and SystemWebHttpContextAdapter). The library is designed to provide these adapters for you. If you find that the built-in capabilities of SystemWebAdapters do not meet a specific requirement, you can still create custom adapters, but they may not be necessary for typical scenarios.

Do you know are what are the names of these adapter classes provided by SystemWebAdapters?

Could someone please try it out?

https://github.com/dotnet/systemweb-adapters/tree/main/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.SystemWebAdapters: Features and Adapters

Can you point me towards a proper answer?

Did you mean something like this: https://apisof.net/catalog/4563503214411d176d52ab7bfb667b83

Please stop pointing out to random library links? Do you know the answer to this question? How should I add use this library with my solution?


if I use Microsoft.AspNetCore.SystemWebAdapters, then do I need to
create my adapter classes, AspNetCoreHttpContextAdapter and
SystemWebHttpContextAdapter?

No, you don't.
Consider the following example:

WebAdaptersDemo.Handler is a .NET Standard 2.0 class library project that references Microsoft.AspNetCore.SystemWebAdapters so the following code executes:
using System.Web;

namespace WebAdaptersDemo.Handler
{
    public class MyHandler
    {
        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
            context.Response.Write("Hello World");
        }
    }
}

WebAdaptersDemo.Web is a .NET Framework 4.7.2 project that references:

WebAdaptersDemo.Handler
Microsoft.AspNetCore.SystemWebAdapters

so that MyHttpHandler (.ashx) executes:
using System.Web;
using WebAdaptersDemo.Handler;

namespace WebAdaptersDemo.Web
{
    public class MyHttpHandler : IHttpHandler
    {

        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            var handler = new MyHandler();
            handler.ProcessRequest(context);
        }
    }
}

WebAdaptersDemo.Web.Core is a Core 8 MVC project that references:

WebAdaptersDemo.Handler
Microsoft.AspNetCore.SystemWebAdapters.CoreServices

so that the below endpoint registers and executes:
app.MapGet("/myhandler", (HttpContext context) =>
    {
        var handler = new MyHandler();
        handler.ProcessRequest(context);
    });

So, the WebAdaptersDemo.Handler class library can be used by both the old (.ashx) and the new projects. Everything else is handled automatically for you by SystemWebAdapters.
